# Regex to detect IE9 and below?

Tags: regex, user-agent

I am trying to write a regex pattern in Java to detect if a user agent is less than or equal to Internet Explorer 9. There are quite a few examples here:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/

The main gist is there will be a string in the user agent string called: "MSIE XXXX). My current regex pattern is this:

```
MSIE ([1-9]|9)
```

Which seems to work except there are problems when I do MSIE 10.0 or MSIE 11.0 it matches. Any ideas on how to only match 1-9 and no 10.0 or 11?

Comment: What's wrong with `MSIE [1-9]` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That it will potentially match IE 10.

Comment: then it need anchors. `^MSIE [1-9]$`

Comment: The user agent string does not end there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In old versions, there is always a dot after the major version number, you can use it in your regex :

`MSIE [1-9]\.`

Another way to write it is to expect one number between 1 and 9 followed by a non number char :

`MSIE [1-9][^0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

only match 5-9 and not 1-9. There are virtually 0 people using IE 4 and below.

Comment: Alternatively use a word boundary. `MSIE ([1-9])\b`.

Comment: That user agent string does not officially exist, consequently it must be spoofed, so who cares.