# Browser detection compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-detection

What you see is a script that will retrieve browser name, version and OS. I took this script off the web some time ago but it was until today a colleague in testing pointed out that it doesn't work in IE9 (I've been developing off Chrome41 and IE11). I know IE's token was changed to "rv" and I assumed both instances of IE would return a value since I've both conditions in the IF statment. However no details are being returned at all in IE9. Ideas?

**JS**

```
//Browser name & version
{
    var unknown = '-';

    //browser
    var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
    var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
    var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

    // Opera
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Opera';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
    }
        // MSIE
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
    }
        // Chrome
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Chrome';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
    }
        // Safari
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Safari';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
        if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
            version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
        }
    }
        // Firefox
    else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
        browser = 'Firefox';
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
    }
        // MSIE 11+
    else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
        browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
        version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
    }
        // Other browsers
    else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
        browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
        version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
        if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
            browser = navigator.appName;
        }
    }
    // trim the version string
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
    if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

    majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
    if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
        version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
    }

    // Operating System Version
    var os = unknown;
    var clientStrings = [
                { s: 'Windows 3.11', r: /Win16/ },
                { s: 'Windows 95', r: /(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/ },
                { s: 'Windows ME', r: /(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/ },
                { s: 'Windows 98', r: /(Windows 98|Win98)/ },
                { s: 'Windows CE', r: /Windows CE/ },
                { s: 'Windows 2000', r: /(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/ },
                { s: 'Windows XP', r: /(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/ },
                { s: 'Windows Server 2003', r: /Windows NT 5.2/ },
                { s: 'Windows Vista', r: /Windows NT 6.0/ },
                { s: 'Windows 7', r: /(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/ },
                { s: 'Windows 8.1', r: /(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/ },
                { s: 'Windows 8', r: /(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/ },
                { s: 'Windows NT 4.0', r: /(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/ },
                { s: 'Windows ME', r: /Windows ME/ },
                { s: 'Android', r: /Android/ },
                { s: 'Open BSD', r: /OpenBSD/ },
                { s: 'Sun OS', r: /SunOS/ },
                { s: 'Linux', r: /(Linux|X11)/ },
                { s: 'iOS', r: /(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/ },
                { s: 'Mac OS X', r: /Mac OS X/ },
                { s: 'Mac OS', r: /(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/ },
                { s: 'QNX', r: /QNX/ },
                { s: 'UNIX', r: /UNIX/ },
                { s: 'BeOS', r: /BeOS/ },
                { s: 'OS/2', r: /OS\/2/ },
                { s: 'Search Bot', r: /(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/ }
    ];
    for (var id in clientStrings) {
        var cs = clientStrings[id];
        if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
            os = cs.s;
            break;
        }
    }

    var osVersion = unknown;

    if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
        osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
        os = 'Windows';
    }

    switch (os) {
        case 'Mac OS X':
            osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
            break;

        case 'Android':
            osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
            break;

        case 'iOS':
            osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
            osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
            break;
    }
}

window.jscd = {
    browser: browser,
    browserVersion: version,
    os: os,
    osVersion: osVersion
};

document.getElementById("browserName").innerHTML = jscd.browser;
document.getElementById("browserVersion").innerHTML = jscd.browserVersion;
document.getElementById("os").innerHTML = "<b>" + jscd.os + "  " + jscd.osVersion + "</b>";
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239932/regex-to-detect-ie9-and-below

(you can catch the version number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i cannot write a comment because i do not have reputation...

Can be the problem due to compatibility mode?

Anyway you may take a look at this http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/ for the possible useragent string.

When you use IE9 in which ELSE IF statement do you enter?

Answer (score 0):

The error wasn't with the tokens or useragents.

One of the requirements of the project was to display the details in colour (green if in date or true and red if out of date or false). however, to achieve that, I used the classlist.add property.

```
// Colour of browser & versions (Red/Green)
if (jscd.browser == "Chrome" && jscd.browserVersion < "41") {
    browserVersion.classList.add('red');
    browserName.classList.add('red');
} else if (jscd.browser == "Chrome" && jscd.browserVersion > "41") {
    browserVersion.classList.add('green');
    browserName.classList.add('green');
}
```

IE9 and below won't support that so i replaced it with .className += ""; and it worked.

```
if (jscd.browser == "Chrome" && jscd.browserVersion < "41") {
    browserVersion.className += "red";
    browserName.className += "red";
} else if (jscd.browser == "Chrome" && jscd.browserVersion > "41") {
    browserVersion.className += "green";
    browserName.className += "green";
}
```